# Find records have count of association > n

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-activerecord, psql

```
class PurchaseOrder < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :purchase_order_materials 
end 
class PurchaseOrderMaterial < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :purchase_order
  belongs_to :material
end
```

I have this query:

```
PurchaseOrderMaterial
  .includes(:purchase_order, :material)
  .where("purchase_orders.provider_id IS NULL AND purchase_orders.status = ? 
          AND (purchase_orders.is_waiting != ? 
               OR purchase_orders.is_waiting IS NULL)", 
         PurchaseOrder.possibleStatus.first, true)
```

All i want it's filter results to purchase_order.purchase_order_materials.count > 1.
Some way to achieve it?

Comment: Please reformat the question (it is very difficult to read right now). Also this query will currently fail because `includes` will not automatically join the relation since you are using a string argument in `where`. That being said if you use `joins` rather than `includes` you will "filter" the results based solely on the join condition

Comment: @engineersmnky in fact the query is actually working, all i need is get records that have more than 1 associated object

Comment: Sorry I failed to notice the [tag:ruby-on-rails-3] tag. Rails 3 parsed the String to determine conditions on the join. In modern rails versions you would need to add `references(:purchase_order)` at a minimum to make this work. Sorry I missed the > 1 part I was thinking >= 1 which is implied by the join table anyway. You could add `where(purchase_order_id: PurchaseOrder.joins(:purchase_order_materials).select(:id).group(:id).having("COUNT(purchase_orders.id) > 1"))` and that should take care of it.

Comment: That being said rails 3.2 was released in 2012 and was officially dropped from support in 2016 I believe, so an upgrade is definitely in order and would be highly recommended. Rails 6.0 is the current version and the currently [maintained versions](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/maintenance_policy.html) for security issues are 6.0 and 5.2.